# A single Kubernetes Cluster running on multiple clouds

Tags: kubernetes, mesos

Is it in any way possible to configure a Kubernetes Cluster that utilizes ressources from multiple IaaS providers at the same time e.g. a cluster running partially on GCE and AWS? Or a Kubernetes Cluster running on your bare metal and an IaaS provider? Maybe in combination with some other tools like Mesos? Are there any other tools like Kubernetes that provide this capability? If it's not possbile with Kubernetes, what would one have to do in order to provide that feature?

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no supported way to achieve what you're trying to do.  But there is a Kubernetes project under way to address it, which goes under the name of Kubernetes Cluster Federation, alternatively known as "Ubernetes".  Further details are available here:

http://www.slideshare.net/quintonh/federation-of-kubernetes-clusters-aka-ubernetes-kubecon-2015-slides-quinton-hoole
http://tinyurl.com/ubernetesv2
http://tinyurl.com/ubernetes-wg-notes