# Can you run Kubernetes nodes on multiple clouds as part of one cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to run a single Kubernetes cluster that includes nodes that are spread across multiple clouds? For example, could you have some nodes running in AWS and some in Azure, and all be a part of the same cluster?

This question was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809727/a-single-kubernetes-cluster-running-on-multiple-clouds) in 2015 but I'm not sure if that answer is still accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a use case of using such environments. For the time we can't use such a way of deployment in Kubernetes documents

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can reach a low latency between the machines then it should not be a problem. There are many reasons to do this but also many to not do it (security, latency, networking problems). I did not attempt to do this yet so if there is someone who has experience in this topic I will gladly welcome some more insights. 
There is an interesting whitepapers and report about multi cloud deployments [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sxg1xXmd0I). You would have to also look at cluster federation described in the Kubernetes official [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/#hybrid-cloud-capabilities) and the tool used for it [Kubefed.](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed) There is another source in medium [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/experimenting-with-cross-cloud-kubernetes-cluster-federation-dfa99f913d54) from 2017 with approach to do this using Juju and Kubefed.

I am going to actually try this this week or in the beggining of next. So I will comeback with some more information.

You can find some information about similar scenario [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGmaOOW3Hl0&feature=youtu.be&list=PLaJlRa-xItwCzuAL3mP6n02vmXab4Bwu-&t=711).